# Difference between the linker flags

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gcc, linker, g++

I'm adding c++ runtime and exception support to the Linux kernel. For that, I need to provide my own `lib/gcc` and `lib/libstdc++`instead of the standard libraries provided by the compiler.

So, I am confused with the flags that are to be passed to the linker. In a normal kernel's top-level Makefile, `LD = $(CROSS_COMPILE)ld` which enables the kernel to use the default standard libraries and startup files. For my kernel I'm using `LD = $(CROSS_COMPILE)ld -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -nostartfiles` as said in a documentation. What I understood from [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) is that passing `-nostdlib` to the linker is that of passing both `-nodefaultlibs -nostartfiles`. What's actually the difference between these flags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These flags are defined in [GCC’s spec files](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html), so the best way to determine the differences between them is to look there:

```
gcc -dumpspecs
```

The relevant part is the `link_command` definition. This shows that `-nostdlib`, `-nodefaultlibs` and `-nostartfiles` have the following impact:

- `%{!nostdlib:%{!nodefaultlibs:%:pass-through-libs(%(link_gcc_c_sequence))}}` — this adds `libgcc`, `libpthread`, `libc`, `libieee` as necessary, using a [macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Driver.html#index-LINK_005fGCC_005fC_005fSEQUENCE_005fSPEC) and the `lib` and `libgcc` spec strings;
- `%{!nostdlib:%{!nostartfiles:%S}}` — this adds the `startfile` spec string, , which specifies the object files to add to handle startup (`crti.o` etc.)
- `%{!nostdlib:%{fvtable-verify=std: -lvtv -u_vtable_map_vars_start -u_vtable_map_vars_end}    %{fvtable-verify=preinit: -lvtv -u_vtable_map_vars_start -u_vtable_map_vars_end}}` — this adds virtual table verification using `libvtv`
- `%{!nostdlib:%{!nodefaultlibs:%{mmpx:%{fcheck-pointer-bounds:    %{static:--whole-archive -lmpx --no-whole-archive %:include(libmpx.spec)%(link_libmpx)}    %{!static:%{static-libmpx:-Bstatic --whole-archive}    %{!static-libmpx:--push-state --no-as-needed} -lmpx     %{!static-libmpx:--pop-state}     %{static-libmpx:--no-whole-archive -Bdynamic %:include(libmpx.spec)%(link_libmpx)}}}}%{mmpx:%{fcheck-pointer-bounds:%{!fno-chkp-use-wrappers:    %{static:-lmpxwrappers}    %{!static:%{static-libmpxwrappers:-Bstatic}    -lmpxwrappers %{static-libmpxwrappers: -Bdynamic}}}}}}}` — this handles `libmpx`
- `%{!nostdlib:%{!nodefaultlibs:%{%:sanitize(address): %{static-libasan:%:include(libsanitizer.spec)%(link_libasan)}    %{static:%ecannot specify -static with -fsanitize=address}}    %{%:sanitize(thread): %{static-libtsan:%:include(libsanitizer.spec)%(link_libtsan)}    %{static:%ecannot specify -static with -fsanitize=thread}}    %{%:sanitize(undefined):%{static-libubsan:-Bstatic} -lubsan %{static-libubsan:-Bdynamic} %{static-libubsan:%:include(libsanitizer.spec)%(link_libubsan)}}    %{%:sanitize(leak): %{static-liblsan:%:include(libsanitizer.spec)%(link_liblsan)}}}}` — this handles the various sanitisation options
- `%{!nostdlib:%{!nodefaultlibs:%(link_ssp) %(link_gcc_c_sequence)}}` — this adds the stack protection options and repeats the C link sequence (whose libraries were already specified at the start)
- `%{!nostdlib:%{!nostartfiles:%E}}` — this adds the `endfile` spec string, which specifies the object files to add to handle left-overs (`crtfastmath.o`, `crtend.o` etc.)

As you understood from the documentation, `-nostdlib` is a superset of `-nodefaultlibs` and `-nostartfiles`. It also disables virtual table verification.

So `-nostdlib` is sufficient to disable all the related features; `-nodefaultlibs` and `-nostartfiles` don’t add anything to it. (But it doesn’t hurt to mention them too.)

Comment: OK I got it. But I cannot understand why there occurs a misalignment of load segments of vmlinux when the line `LD = $(CROSS_COMPILE)ld -nostdlib ` is  changed to `LD = $(CROSS_COMPILE)ld -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -nostartfiles`. Instead of aligning at a mutiple of 2MB, they align at 1KB or something like that.